# White line between divs for some different mobile views

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, mobile

I created a minimal reproduceable example where I took out all styling except the background color and a height so it can be easily visible. Can anyone explain why there is a white line between the divs? It seems to be random based on the screen size. This issue is in chrome and Edge. I have not checked other browsers yet. I first thought it was an issue with Chromes mobile viewer but the same problem exists in Edge. Does anyone know what is causing this or how to resolve it? [**Here is the code**](https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-jones-7bwyr2?file=/src/App.js&resolutionWidth=368&resolutionHeight=494). When you go to this link, you can switch between mobile views to see the issue as shown in the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never found out why this is happening but the only solution I have found is to simply put the background color in the parent div and add a percentage to each child div like below.

```
.main{
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  background: rgba(1, 65, 99, 0.99);
}
.main-bottom-div {
  height: 65%;
}
.main-middle-div {
  height: 45%;
}

<div className={"main"}>
  <div className={"main-middle-div"}>
    <div style={{ padding: "0px 20px" }}>test </div>
  </div>
  <div className={"main-bottom-div"}>
    <div>test</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The cause of that white lines is the `body` of your HTML. Adding this global reset may help you get rid of that white lines.

`* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }`

So the content of your CSS data may look like this.

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.main-bottom-div {
  min-height: 35vh;
  background-color: rgb(1, 65, 99);
}
.main-middle-div {
  height: 10vh;
  background-color: rgb(1, 65, 99);
}
```

Hope this could help you in some ways. :)

Comment: Thanks you. Although this did get rid of that white line, it added white lines around the background color on the border of the screen.

Comment: This also didn't work on my large scale application for some reason. It basically has no affect.

Comment: [Click here to see the code I am referring too where this doesn't work](https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-jones-7bwyr2?file=/src/App.js:77-133&resolutionWidth=368&resolutionHeight=638)

Comment: This is not the solution and I accidentally upvoted it. [HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-jones-7bwyr2?file=/src/App.js&resolutionWidth=368&resolutionHeight=494) is a link to this not working. Basically if anything is above these 2 div's the white line appears. Very very weird.

Comment: @JustinO You can playaraound your css like adding `margin: -5px;` in your `.main-bottom-div` class to remove that white line.

Comment: that is not a solution for a non minimal version. It produces other issues and also makes this one worse. Plus it doesn't make sense. Why would anyone have to do thi?. Why is this even happening? I have never encountered this before.

Comment: The reason it wont work is because in the actual code I am using an rgba instead of rgb and the background has opacity to it. Applying that margin gives a worse effect. [See it here](https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-jones-7bwyr2?file=/src/styles.css&resolutionWidth=368&resolutionHeight=626)

Comment: I'm sorry that i couldn't help. Just like i said, you can fix the issue on your css code. I'm glad you find a better solution.